# Changing dynamic dropdown to hardcode while keeping conditons

Tags: php, html

This should be simple but Its confusing the heck out of me.  I need to change the following html

```
 <td class="text-left">
       <div class="component-dropdowns">
          <select name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_type]" class="form-control">
             <?php foreach ($component_groups as $component_group) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $component_group['group_type']; ?>" <?php echo ($component_module['component_type'] == $component_group['group_type']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?php echo $component_group['group_type']; ?></option>
             <?php } ?>  
          </select>
       </div>
    </td>
```

I need to remove the foreach that reads the array from the controller, and change to a hard coded list like this:

```
<option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option><option value="Email"><?php echo "Email" ?></option><option value="Text Message"><?php echo "Text Message" ?></option><option value="Direct Mail"><?php echo "Direct Mail" ?></option><option value="Transnational Email"><?php echo "Transnational Email" ?></option><option value="EVENT"><?php echo "Event" ?></option>
```

The problem is the first hunk of html also checks to see if a type has already been selected. I need to add the new drop-down list while keeping the same functionality

Comment: Why exactly do you need to remove the `foreach`?

Comment: the array was getting the options from a table but I was asked to change it from that. I was asked to have that done on the view